# SSRS-MDX Slicer(Passing big String as a Slicer)

Tags: mdx

I am not sure if this is possible , this might look strange, but I am having nightmare implementing this,

I have a strange requirement where I need to pass a string that is 20000 characters wide.

Let me give a little background

I have a Dimension  in the cube with an attribute called Product Line Code which might have 20000 unique values example(1-20000), the user wants to store all these values into a Report Filter table and get these values passed to SSRS Report which should in turn get passed to the MDX query to use as slicing criteria  without any user intervention in the SSRS end.

Following is what I have done which is not a big deal I know
wrote a small function in SQL that reads the values from Report Filter table to create a set and return as one string like
{[Product].[Product Line].[Code].&[1],[Product].[Product Line].[Code].&[2],................................,[Product].[Product Line].[Code].&[20000]}

when I call this function in SSRS Dataset, it returns a blank value though it works in SQL without a problem, I am doing the samething for other slices with relatively little size when compared to this one and they all work fine.

My question is how do I pass this big value string through SSRS parameter to use it as a slicer in MDX.

Is there any other  option, has any one come across this kind of Scenario.

Appreciating your help

Thanks
Alex Sebas

Answer (score 0):

Are there just a few distinct standard sets of [Product Line] codes? The reason I ask is that could you potentially create a list of defined [sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145963.aspx) and use those as a parameter in the MDX. So in report services they simply have a drop down of the various sets of Product Lines.

Comment: The problem is SSRS size limit, I found out a work around and it worked, I acrually wrore a Stored procedure cut the whole list into chunks  < 7000 characters and stored them in a temp table and returned  them to SSRS, where I used Join to connect them again within MDX and it worked